# how to compare 2 dates with different formats in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 dates like the following.

```
End_Date = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365), '01/01/2000')
Cur_Date = SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111
```

I want to check if `End_Date` is less than `Cur_Date` so that I could do a particular update.

My current query is like the following

```
update bed
set Status_Avai_Occ = 
    case when (
                ( select  End_Date 
                  from Patient_Record 
                  where b_ID= @b and
                  End_Date <> '-' 
                  and End_Date is not null
                ) <  (
                       SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
                     )
               ) then 'Available'
```

but I am getting the following error:

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Comment: What is the logic to compare End_Date to '-'?

Comment: What is the datatype of End_Date in your table?

Comment: Stop treating dates as strings. Keep them in `datetime` variables/columns at all times, and things should just work.

Comment: What Damien said. `Comparison operators can be used on all expressions except expressions of the text, ntext, or image data types.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx  getdate() returns datetime type as does DateAdd() when the date argument is a string literal. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Extending the comment.  Your randomly-generated date using DateAdd returns a datetime at midnight whereas getdate() returns a datetime whose time component reflects the current time. So you need to "round" getdate() down to midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only line I can see which would give that error is

```
End_Date <> '-'
```

which seems to imply that End_Date is a DATE or DATETIME column. If so you can simple compare dates using:

```
End_Date < GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round getdate() to midnight so:

```
         SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```